# How do I migrate rosbuild_add_rostest_labelled to catkin?

Tags: rostest

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The catkin [migrating from rosbuild](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild) page provides no answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55382/how-do-i-migrate-rosbuild_add_rostest_labelled-to-catkin?/) by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25443 on 2013-02-16

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No one answered this, so I'll post my own solution. Suppose you have a device driver with unit tests that only work on a machine with that device attached. It will fail, if run as a regression test by the build farm.

So, in the catkin CMakeLists.txt, wrap `add_rostest()` inside a CMake `if ()` block, like this:

```
if (${DEVICE_TEST})
  add_rostest(tests/camera_node_hz.test)
  add_rostest(tests/camera_nodelet_hz.test)
endif (${DEVICE_TEST})
```

Those tests will only run when explicitly configured via CMake:

```
$ cd build
$ cmake ../src -DDEVICE_TEST=true 
$ make run_tests
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3